# Why does the navigation drawer not navigate when implementing appbar variations?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to implement a navigation drawer that supports 2 variations of the app bar. The project has single Activity and top-level destination fragments: some will use the default Toolbar, and some will use CollapsingToolbarLayout with an inner imageView. However, the app does not navigate to destinations by clicking on the drawer.

Android documentation leads to conflict about where to call `setupWithNavController()`.

[In the support documentation for app bar variations](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/integrations/ui#support_app_bar_variations), it is written:

> The navigation configuration logic is the same for both of these fragments, except that you should call **`setupWithNavController()` from within each fragment's `onViewCreated()` method**, instead of initializing them from the activity...

However, in the [implementation part of the navigation drawer](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/integrations/ui#add_a_navigation_drawer), the documentation says:

> Next, in your main activity class, call **`setupWithNavController()` from your main activity's `onCreate()` method**, as shown below...

I've tried to make the necessary adaptations, but I'm missing something.
The app runs without errors, but when clicking on items in the drawer, nothing happens.
I need the navigation to happen, and the top bar to react showing the names of each fragment and displaying the image in the fragment using the CollapsingToolbarLayout.
Here's what I last tried using an Android Studio navigation drawer template:

`activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/content_main"
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

`content_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

`fragment_home.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="152dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:expanded="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            style="?attr/collapsingToolbarLayoutLargeStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="@color/purple_500"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="top"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
            app:titleCollapseMode="scale">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbarHome"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`fragment_gallery.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.gallery.GalleryFragment">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarGallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_gallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`activity_main_drawer.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="@string/menu_home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="@string/menu_gallery" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

`mobile_navigation.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:name="com.devreis.ofertas.teste.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:name="com.devreis.ofertas.teste.ui.gallery.GalleryFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_gallery"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_gallery" />
</navigation>
```

`MainActivity.kt`

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import com.devreis.ofertas.teste.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val binding: ActivityMainBinding by lazy { ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) }
    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout by lazy { binding.drawerLayout }
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery
            ), drawerLayout
        )
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController
    }
}
```

`HomeFragment.kt`

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.devreis.ofertas.teste.MainActivity
import com.devreis.ofertas.teste.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding

class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.textHome.text = "Home fragment"
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(
        view: View,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val navController = findNavController()
        val drawerLayout = (requireActivity() as MainActivity).drawerLayout
        binding.collapsingToolbarLayout.setupWithNavController(binding.toolbarHome, navController, drawerLayout)
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

`GalleryFragment.kt`

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.devreis.ofertas.teste.MainActivity
import com.devreis.ofertas.teste.databinding.FragmentGalleryBinding

class GalleryFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentGalleryBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentGalleryBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.textGallery.text = "Gallery fragment"
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(
        view: View,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val navController = findNavController()
        val drawerLayout = (requireActivity() as MainActivity).drawerLayout
        binding.toolbarGallery.setupWithNavController(navController, drawerLayout)
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

`build.gradle:app`

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.devreis.ofertas.teste'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.devreis.ofertas.teste"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.3'
}
```

Comment: So the default is in the activity, but for a specific scenario, you move that code to your fragment. Which part are you confused about? What does 'does not navigate' mean?

Comment: Edited by adding an example. According to the documentation, to support variations of application bars, you need to call setupWithNavController() on the fragments. But if you don't call this method in the activity, clicking on items in the drawer won't navigate to the destinations. How to implement it so that both the navigation drawer works and the correct display of each toolbar specific to each fragment?